# create a formula to convert 1 varchar field w/date and 1 varchar w/time into 1 datetime field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have an existing report that has 2 `varchar` fields.  1 holds a date, 2 holds a time.  I need to create a formula concatenating both and then use that formula to sort the report by.  Example:

```
SCHEDULED_DATE             SCHEDULED_TIME
2018-04-26 00:00:00.000    1:00 PM
2018-04-26 00:00:00.000    NULL
```

I want to add the 2 fields together and then sort.
In SQL I can do the following but in crystal reports, it fails to convert properly and throws an error.

```
ORDER BY Convert(Datetime, SCHEDULED_DATE + Convert(time,ISNULL(SCHEDULED_TIME, '00:00:00.000')))
```

Here is my attempt at the Crystal Report formula:

```
If IsNull ({Inspections.SCHEDULED_TIME})
Then CDateTime(CDATE({Inspections.SCHEDULED_DATE}) + Time('00:00:00.000'))
Else CDateTime(CDate({Inspections.SCHEDULED_DATE})+ CTime({Inspections.SCHEDULED_TIME}))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you post error?

Comment: Error: Bad time format string. Details: errorKind Error in formula.

Comment: New Formula that I'm trying:

Comment: If IsNull ({Inspections.SCHEDULED_TIME})
Then {Inspections.SCHEDULED_DATE}+ CTime(00,00,00)
Else {Inspections.SCHEDULED_DATE}+ CTime({Inspections.SCHEDULED_TIME})

Comment: Is new formula working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, date and time values should never be stored as text.

Better use the appropriate data-types of your DBMS.

Then see multiple issues in your formula:

- `CDate` and `CDateTime` don't support milliseconds
- `Date` and `Time` values can't be concatenated with a `+`
- The `SCHEDULED_DATE`-column already contains a time-part and you (try to) add one more
- When concatenating the date and time part, separate them with a blank space

So, you have to remove the time part and concatenate the columns without converting them to `Date` or `Time`:

```
If IsNull ({Inspections.SCHEDULED_TIME})
Then CDateTime(CDATE({Inspections.SCHEDULED_DATE}))
Else CDateTime(Left({Inspections.SCHEDULED_DATE},10)+" "+{Inspections.SCHEDULED_TIME})
```

**Note:** I removed the time `00:00:00.000` in the "True"-part completely as it's not required when you set all to zero anyway.

Comment: We didn't create the software, thus we have no control over the db structure or data type definitions.  I should have mentioned this as well as I'm updating a canned report in the system.  As it turns out the time field allows for text such as Day, AM, PM, Any.  These values were blowing up the conversion to a time.  I updated the .dat file to update the temp table with 12:00:00 (same for Nulls and Empty Spaces).  Now all records have a time that can be sorted on via the formula field.  Thanks for your guidance.